# Animating background gradient with cutout shape

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click inspect element I get this:
[it seems to use canvas, so should I do a course on this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ7Hn.png)

The other option i can think of is css keyframes similar tot he Kahoot website, so you could have say a rectangle shape which changes colors.

My issues are:

1. How would you get the triangle shape seen on the stripe website.
2. How do you animate it such that the colors change?
3. Is something like web-flow good for this to allow allow response design?

I understand its a huge question but I'm totally lost although willing to google things if you have any idea on what things i should be reading.

Stripe website: https://stripe.com/gb

What I'd love to accomplish:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtIIH.jpg)

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd probably actually try to do it with SVG.  Seems like it would be easier.

Comment: Find a course/tutorial in WebGL, shaders. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_shaders_to_apply_color_in_WebGL

Comment: @Brad so you wouldn't use canvas?

Answer (score 2):

The triangle is achieved using by skewing the image, if you examine the triangle a bit more you will notice triangle continues over the top the screen.

This is a rough version of how they implemented it.
look at the div containing the canvas for more details (it has the classes HomepageHeroGradient, Gradient, and isLoaded)

```css
.triangle {
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-12deg);
  transform: skewY(-12deg);
  height:120px;
  width:120px;
}

.hide-top {
  /* force the top of the triangle outside the screen */
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  original
</div>

<div class="triangle hide-top">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  hide the top<br>
  of the triangle
  
</div>
```

Regarding how they got the pretty colours i am not entirely certain. But I know it is animated by javascript, because it doesn't work if you disable JavaScript on the page.

My best guess is that the waves that you see are some kind of sin wave [Tutorial of sinewave in canvas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNmTubIDZOY). And they added some kind of blur effect to it.

Regarding webflow, I have no idea. I have never used it. But based on the their tutorial it looks kind of awesome. And since webflow allows you to add custom JavaScript it should be possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help and your time man! You're absolutely right, I didn't even realise ti wasn't a triangle until you pointed it out.Quick question, i've seen -webkit-transform being used, what is the difference between this and simply transform? And even the tutorial you mentioned uses canvas, do you think it's worth learning then?

Comment: @github292929 -webkit- , -moz-, -o- and -ms- are called [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) they are used when introducing new css features for compatability reasons. Regarding canvas, I think you can get the desired effect if you tweek Senatrius answer.

Answer (score 1):

frithjof already gave you the perfect answer to achieve the slanted effect using skew CSS property.

As for the animated gradient effect, I'd suggest looking into animated canvas gradients. From what I can tell, it seems to involve a lot of math that goes right over my head. But I did find this on codepen, albeit very simplified version of it, maybe you can reverse engineer it and figure out what makes it move.

https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/vOPZBv

HTML

```
<canvas id="canv" width="32" height="32">
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
var c = document.getElementById('canv');
var $ = c.getContext('2d');


var col = function(x, y, r, g, b) {
  $.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
  $.fillRect(x, y, 1,1);
}
var R = function(x, y, t) {
  return( Math.floor(192 + 64*Math.cos( (x*x-y*y)/300 + t )) );
}

var G = function(x, y, t) {
  return( Math.floor(192 + 64*Math.sin( (x*x*Math.cos(t/4)+y*y*Math.sin(t/3))/300 ) ) );
}

var B = function(x, y, t) {
  return( Math.floor(192 + 64*Math.sin( 5*Math.sin(t/9) + ((x-100)*(x-100)+(y-100)*(y-100))/1100) ));
}

var t = 0;

var run = function() {
  for(x=0;x<=35;x++) {
    for(y=0;y<=35;y++) {
      col(x, y, R(x,y,t), G(x,y,t), B(x,y,t));
    }
  }
  t = t + 0.120;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
}

run();
```

Regarding webflow, I'm not too familiar with it. Some years ago when I last ran into it, it didn't seem to support js files very well so this wouldn't have worked. I don't know if it works now, but if it does, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response man, people like you are saints. So should I try and learn canvas HTML basics? How did you find this on codePen btw? Do you think I could even copy it and use it? Thanks!

Comment: @github292929 To be fair, it was more luck that I found it.  simply googled "animated canvas background" which didn't get me what I wanted so I added "gradient" to the query and found a link to a [tutorial site](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animated-gradient-background/) that led to the codepen.

You could learn the basics but I think this is beyond what a basics tutorial will teach you. I suggest looking up more specific tutorials as frithjof suggested, see how to achieve similar effects. You can just use this too https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/licensing